# error adding a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE ROUTE ADD FOREIGN KEY (RID) REFERENCES RESERVATION(RID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

but it generates me an error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`SmarTrek`.`#sql-91e_d09`, CONSTRAINT `FK_RID` FOREIGN KEY (`RID`) REFERENCES `RESERVATION` (`RID`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

In designer mode, here's what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would meant that you already have data in the ROUTE table that does not satisfy the foreign key constraint.

To find the offending records, so you can update them to some other value (that exists), you can use

```
select *
from route
where rid not in (select rid from reservation)
```

Answer (score 0):

THERE may b 2 reasons

- there may b some row in `ROUTE` TABLE which have `RID` that does not exist in `RESERVATION(RID)`
- or check the  **DATATYPE** OF `ROUTE (RID)` & `RESERVATION(RID)` both should be same ( unsigned/signed)