# MySQL Error #1452 - Trying to add foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

What I'm trying to do is create a Foreign Key for the accounts table to accountID but phpMyAdmin is giving me the following error..

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db123`.`#sql-910_11a1`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-910_11a1_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`adminID`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`accountID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

What does the error mean and how can I add the foreign key?

[image: Screen shot of error]

CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE administrators(
  Username VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, adminID INTEGER(1)
, accountID INTEGER(2)
, Hashed_Password VARCHAR(64)
, Salt VARCHAR(32)
, first_name VARCHAR(8)
, last_name VARCHAR(8)
, Email VARCHAR(25)
, Join_Date VARCHAR(16)
);
INSERT INTO administrators(Username,adminID,accountID,Hashed_Password,Salt,first_name,last_name,Email,Join_Date) VALUES ('admin',1,30,'9d26a3c61c0e2ce5c980ad8c7fff13c08cf898b6f3786930c73b68e3b88ad779','002640cb549ba08ee90cd79aee89cce7','Your','name','your email','2014/01/13 14:00');
INSERT INTO administrators(Username,adminID,accountID,Hashed_Password,Salt,first_name,last_name,Email,Join_Date) VALUES ('adminkt',2,31,'19612ae3ed04b7c224ba12db07be5ce0915eed3de351ccbf60508f948b476e5a','15cec5205c9e34355287acbb4d096a08','Kristi','Turman','kristi@gmail.com','2014/01/01 09:00');
INSERT INTO administrators(Username,adminID,accountID,Hashed_Password,Salt,first_name,last_name,Email,Join_Date) VALUES ('adminst',3,32,'0fec1e61a67e7a0fd3623e0d9d656fc765462557c2a5f5933ee37b63d9864d80','a1dca222c170e3d2b5dd2557d5a57090','Scott','Turman','turman@telstra.com.au','2014/01/20 14:30');
INSERT INTO administrators(Username,adminID,accountID,Hashed_Password,Salt,first_name,last_name,Email,Join_Date) VALUES ('adminrw',4,33,'8a35fd6de1e692dfa8277c405f93bba34926176285c85a13634e54e051b576f3','09d1fe391935b75f798053f866ee5052','Richard','Weathers','richo@gmail.com','2014/01/20 16:00');
INSERT INTO administrators(Username,adminID,accountID,Hashed_Password,Salt,first_name,last_name,Email,Join_Date) VALUES ('adminnc',5,34,'d54dc8e24b12ba4805777d6b6eac977094b73962a15e04f227ec40eb6ec56432','4d069acd30e4b0c6eb5e5f36c01d1482','Nicholas','Cutter','nicholas.cutter@gmail.com','2014/01/22 13:00');
```

Comment: If you put the error message "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" into google you could read hundreds of relevant questions and articles.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Remove the foreign key constraint, drop the child first.

Comment: maybe you have defined the wrong foreign key?  post the code/?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error adding a foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509376/error-adding-a-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: in table definition are foreign constraints defined. when inserting or updating a record, you don't fulfill the requirements.

Comment: @Robert Code added above

Comment: @Torrezzzz Code added above

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely that you have records in your `administrators` table that doesn't match with records in the `account` table. If you want to add a foreign key like so : `administrators.adminID -> accounts.accountID`, you have to make sure all the records in `administrators` have an `adminID` corresponding to the `accountID` field of the `accounts` table.

If there is no matching record in the `accounts` table, then your `ALERT TABLE` fails.

For instance, you have to have at least 5 records in your `accounts` table with an `accountID` from 1 to 5.

Comment: What records do you have in your `accounts` table ?

Comment: You are trying to make a foreign key on `adminID` here. Maybe you want to foreign key the `accountID` field of the `administrators` table ? The ids won't match with your `accounts` table

Comment: I suggest emptying both table, making change on them and then reinsert records, making sure the ids matches between both

Comment: I really think you want to make a foreign key on `administrators.accountID` not `administrators.adminID` take a look at your `ALERT TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

---

Maybe you defined a foreign key on `adminID` to the `accounts` table on the `accountID` field, now you are trying to add a tuple to the administrator table with an adminID that doesn't exists in the account table.

open phpmyadmin, look at the indexes section on administrator table (administrator->Structure->Indexes) and remove any unuseful index created.

[EDIT]

account table doesn't contain the adminID you are trying to insert above!

Comment: What do you suggest I change